# SQL Joining tables - To only display rows that have matching parameters

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that I am attempting to join but to only display rows of data based on specific parameters.

Table one: "orders"

Table two: "cash_tracking"

Matching parameters from both tables: "orders.user_id" and "cash_tracking.user_id" and the user_id is 2640

The result I want to see is all the "orders.name" from the "user_id=2640" on a specific shop "shop_id = 7777" and based on a specific register number from the "cash_tracking" table eg. "cash_transaction_reg=444454"

However, when I run my query it shows me every single order on this shop instead of the ones related to the user 2640 on this specific register - 444454

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT orders.name
FROM orders
Inner JOIN cash_tracking
ON orders.user_id = cash_tracking.user_id 
WHERE orders.shop_id = 7777
AND cash_tracking.user_id=2640
AND cash_tracking.cash_transaction_reg=444454
```

Comment: Assuming you have a `SELECT`, the logic looks fine.  You are probably not running the entire `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT orders.name
FROM orders
Inner JOIN cash_tracking
ON orders.user_id = cash_tracking.user_id 
WHERE orders.shop_id = 7777 AND orders.user_id=2640
AND cash_tracking.cash_transaction_reg=444454

Comment: Thanks Gordon, i am def doing something wrong here. As it is listing every known Order on the store 7777, even those not part of the Cash register 444454 nor the User 2640. How would I know if i am not running the entire `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You select all orders for user_id, shoud be some join orders.Id = cash_tracking.OrderId